# Rails html render to string

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, render, erb

How can I render an HTML view into a string(saved in the database) to be able to render it back from it in rails?

```
def show_offer
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'offer_template_one', :layout => 'templates'}
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf => 'oferta',
      :template => 'templates/show_offer.pdf.erb',
      :layout => "layouts/templates.html.erb",
      :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('public', "Oferta.pdf")
    end
  end
end
```

This is the method through which I'm rendering my view

Thanks!

Comment: you want to cache everything or just this one page or just one part of this one page?

Comment: @dax sorry, I don't really want to cache it. I want to render it into a string. I've edited my question.

Comment: sorry but i am still not able to understand what is your requirement???

Comment: @Milind I am rendering this offer_template_one.html.erb from my show_offer action and I want to also render it as a string and store it in the database.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I got it to work with render_to_string method:

```
@offer_string = render_to_string(:template => 'templates/offer_template_one.html.erb', :layout => false)
```

Comment: You shouldn't even have to specify the template - it'll use the action name (with the extension of the format specified) by default and yield that to the layout of your choosing.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Renders the clear text "hello world" with status code 200
render :text => "hello world!"

# Renders the clear text "Explosion!"  with status code 500
render :text => "Explosion!", :status => 500

# Renders the clear text "Hi there!" within the current active layout (if one exists)
render :text => "Hi there!", :layout => true

# Renders the clear text "Hi there!" within the layout
# placed in "app/views/layouts/special.r(html|xml)"
render :text => "Hi there!", :layout => "special"
```